# How to avoid std::string copy on protobuf reflection SetString()?

Tags: c++, string, performance, protocol-buffers

Is there any method to avoid `std::string` copy for `void SetString(Message * message, const FieldDescriptor * field, std::string value) const`.

Is it possible to set with `const char* data` and `size_t data_size` ?

Comment: With C++17, [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) has been introduced for this purpose. However, you have to use it carefully: A `std::string_view` relies on the life-time of what is viewed, and you (the programmer) are in charge to consider this. (I must admit that I'm really not sure whether this is applicable for Googles protobuf in your case.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any method to avoid std::string copy for void SetString(Message * message, const FieldDescriptor * field, std::string value) const

Yes. The `value` parameter is passed by value, so you can call `std::move` to move a string object, instead of copy it:

```
string your_value;
reflect->SetString(message, field, std::move(your_value));
```

> Is it possible to set with const char* data and size_t data_size?

No, you cannot do that. Since the `value` parameter is of type `std::string`, you have to construct a `std::string` object with the `data` pointer and `data_size` length. So far, there's no way to avoid copy, in order to create a `std::string` object with a pointer.

Comment: The API `SetString` accepts `std:string` instead of `std::string&&`. How would `std::move` work in this case?

Comment: With `std::move`, the `value` parameter is move constructed. So there's no copy.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated:

> void set_foo(string&& value) (C++11 and beyond): Sets the value of the field, moving from the passed string. After calling this, has_foo() will return true and foo() will return a copy of value.

Comment: In my case, it relates to Reflection API `SetString`, so it's not about setting the field directly.